# Why do I have to skip the month of february in the for loop and use mes->fevereiro[j] instead of mes->meses[1][j]?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, struct

```
typedef struct 

{ 

    char janeiro[31];
    char *fevereiro;
    char marco[31];
    char abril[30];
    char maio[31];
    char junho[30];
    char julho[31];
    char agosto[31];
    char setembro[30];
    char outubro[31];
    char novembro[30];
    char dezembro[31];

    int mesSize[12] = { 31, 28, 31, 30, 31 , 30, 31, 31, 30 , 31, 30, 31 };
    char *meses[12]={ janeiro, fevereiro, marco, abril, maio, junho, julho, agosto, setembro, outubro, novembro, dezembro };

} MESES;


int n_diasK(MESES *mes)

{
    int i, j, counter=0;

    for (i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {


        for(j = 0; j < (mes->mesSize[i]) ; j++){

            if (i == 1)
            {
                if (mes->fevereiro[j] == 'K');
                counter++;

            }

            else if (mes->meses[i][j] == 'K' )
                counter++;

        }


    }

    return counter;

}

void menu()
{

  MESES mes;

  randLetters(year,&mes);

  n_diasK(&mes);

}
```

Ok this is the relevant part of the real program, basically what the program does is it asks for the user to select a year and then it assigns to each day of each month a random letter, in the randLetters() function, and it then has to find how many days have the letter 'K'. In the structure the char *fevereiro(february) is a pointer instead of an array because I need to calculate the leap year. The code I posted above works but I had to include a special case for february `if(mes->fevereiro[j] == 'K')` because if run the for loop without this check it crashes when it reaches `mes->meses[1][j] == 'K'`.

Comment: I would think that `char *2Darray` should be `char **2Darray`, seeing as it's an array of arrays of characters, right?

Comment: this can't compile.

Comment: Need to at least malloc some space for ob first

Comment: `char *2Darray[2]={somearray, somepointer};` is not valid C, both because the variable name starts with a digit, and because C doesn't have in-struct initializers. Apart from that, you are accessing through `ob` without having initialized it beforehand.

Comment: When you initialize `2Darray`, you're using the existing value of `somepointer`. Assigning to `somepointer` after that doesn't update the value of `2Darray[1]` with its new value.

Comment: sorry I know, it was just for demonstration purposes, I'll correct that

Comment: Have you actually tried this? Which compiler was able to compile this?

Comment: There is still the problem of that in-class initializer. I never expected to say that, but C is not C++14!

Comment: Im not actually using this code, this is just to demonstrate my question, im using visual studio 15

Comment: Well, make your example behave as you say it does, then come back.

Comment: I know that, this was just to demonstrate my question, the *ob I actually get it as a parameter for the function in the real program

Comment: the code is just to big to put ir here, my question is just why it works with the array but not with the pointer

Comment: Then remove irrelevant code until you have something that you can post, and actually reproduces the problem. There's no way we can tell what's wrong with your real code from a partial recreation in pseudo-C syntax...

Comment: It would be better to declare February as `char fevereiro[29];` and then set `mesSize[1]` to 28 or 29 as needed. The fact that the February array may be bigger than necessary shouldn't hurt anything.

Comment: Yes I know but I am curious as to why it does not work

Comment: Hard to say, since A) you still haven't posted a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and B) the code you have posted is not valid C code.

Comment: the program only crashes when i remove  if (i == 1)
            {
                if (mes->fevereiro[j] == 'K');
                counter++;

            }

Comment: And it is valid C code since I copied it directly from the program

Comment: You're most likely compiling with a C++ compiler. A true C compiler won't allow the initializers in the structure definition.

Comment: Yes im using a C++ compiler, but is that the source of the problem im asking?

Answer (score 1):

I believe the problem is that this allocation:

```
  char *2Darray[2]={somearray, somepointer};
```

doesn't behave as you expect for the entire lifetime of `somepointer`.

That is to say, when you allocate memory, and then have `somepointer` point to that memory, `2Darray[1]` is still a char* that points somewhere else. Whatever value `somepointer` was holding/pointing to when the struct was initialized will be the value in `2Darray[1]`.